# Why following query(given below) results into no rows?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, sql-update

I have a table called subjects. I want to update faculty, program, and subjects. User selects program and then corresponding faculty, and then selects corresponding subjects. No when i am updating the records, only two fileds are being updated but only one subject is being updated with repitition. My code to update the fields is as follows:

```
string SQLString2 = "";
            OleDbCommand SQLCommand = new OleDbCommand();
            foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
            {
                foreach (string subName in (item.ToString().Split('+')))
                {
                    SQLString2 = "UPDATE subjects SET program = '" + program + "', faculty = '" + faculty + "', subjectN = '" + subName + "' WHERE RollNo = " + rollNumber + " AND regYear = " + regNumber + " AND program = '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND faculty = '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
                    SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString2;
                    SQLCommand.Connection = database;
                    int response2;
                    try
                    {
                        response2 = SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Faculty and program are being updated successfully but subject is being updated as like this:

```
English
English
English
English
English
```

Is my query right?

Comment: What is the value of `subName`? Are you sure it isn't empty string? Did you debug your code? Did you try your command in your database manager first? Is it works there? And always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. IMO, `SQLCommand` is not a good variable name as a `OleDbCommand`. Also use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and objects.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  If ExecuteNonQuery is returning 0, then no rows were updated.  BTW:  By not using parameters, your query is susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: On debugging i can see the expected values. But only 'English' is being updated there for every subject.

Answer (score 1):

So if you update subject to spanish, then to french, and then to english
Well after all that subject = english
And for program and faculty you are just changing them to the same thing each loop

On response - if that returns 0 then I would believe it
I suspect you are not evaluating things properly

This would be more efficient (and is what you are doing)

```
foreach (var item in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    foreach (string subName in (item.ToString().Split('+')))
    {
        SQLString2 = "UPDATE subjects SET program = '" + program + "', faculty = '" + faculty + "', subjectN = '" + subName + "' WHERE RollNo = " + rollNumber + " AND regYear = " + regNumber + " AND program = '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND faculty = '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";        
    }
    SQLCommand.CommandText = SQLString2;
    SQLCommand.Connection = database;
    int response2;
    try
    {
        response2 = SQLCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah i would be looking into it.

Comment: Please check my question here as well in this regard. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467545/how-to-perform-update-operation-on-two-tables-having-two-similar-fields-and-one

Comment: Please check my answer to this stated question.