# How to perform UPDATE operation on two tables having two similar fields and one different field?

Tags: c#, .net, database, ms-access, sql-update

I have got **two** tables named "**studentBio**" and "**subjects**". Fields of both tables are being given below(with some values): On the form i have got something like this:
[image: Form to update fields]
**AND** in **checkedlistbox1** i am showing corresponding subjects in the form like A+B+C. Which after retrieving from user would be split on the basis of '+' and be added into **subjects** table all at once.

1. Fields of **studentBio** table are given as follows: **WHERE** (RollNo, RegYear,program, and faculty combine to make **composite** primary key):

   ```
   RollNo     RegYear   stuName     program       faculty         phoneNuber    Address

   1         2010      John       Intermediate  Pre-Engineering  343483834    London

   2         2011      Leonard    Intermediate  Pre-Medical      454545445    NewYork

   3         2012      Henry      Graduation    B.A              565656565    Oslo
   ```
2. Similary fields of **subjects** table are as follows: **WHERE**
   (RollNo, RegYear,program, and faculty combine to make **composite**
   primary key):

   ```
   RollNo     RegYear   program       faculty           subjectName 

   1          2010     Intermediate   Pre-Engineering    A
   1          2010     Intermediate   Pre-Engineering    B
   1          2010     Intermediate   Pre-Engineering    C
   2          2011     Intermediate   Pre-Medical        D
   2          2011     Intermediate   Pre-Medical        E
   2          2011     Intermediate   Pre-Medical        F
   ```

and so on. Now lets come to the **problem**. What i am doing is **UPDATING** (**faculty and program**) in both tables and **subjectN** in **subjects table**. What i have done so far is that i have updated only **studentBio** table which is quite easy but i can't figure-out as how could i structure my update query to update **subjects** table? Can somebody please help me structuring the query?

Comment: Could you write the UPDATE query you already have - the one for **studentsBio**?

Comment: Yes i could. string update_Personal = "UPDATE studentBio SET program = ProgramU, faculty = FacultyU WHERE RollNo = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.rollNumber7_combo.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " AND RegYear = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " AND program = '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND faculty = '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, please try this restructured version of your query:

```
string update_Personal = "UPDATE studentBio INNER JOIN subjects ON studentBio.RollNo = subjects.RollNo AND studentBio.RegYear = subjects.RegYear AND studentBio.program = subjects.program AND studentBio.faculty = subjects.faculty SET studentBio.program = ProgramU, studentBio.faculty = FacultyU, subjects.subjectName = SubjectNameU WHERE studentBio.RollNo = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.rollNumber7_combo.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " AND studentBio.RegYear = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " AND studentBio.program = '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND studentBio.faculty = '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
```

I've added the following parts to make it update `subjects` table:

1. `studentBio INNER JOIN subjects ON studentBio.RollNo = subjects.RollNo AND studentBio.RegYear = subjects.RegYear AND studentBio.program = subjects.program AND studentBio.faculty = subjects.faculty` - this part joins the `subjects` table making it's update possible
2. `, subjects.subjectName = SubjectNameU` - fragment in the `SET` block updating subjectName column in subjects table
3. `WHERE studentBio.RollNo = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.rollNumber7_combo.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " AND studentBio.RegYear = " + Convert.ToInt32(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString()) + " AND studentBio.program = '" + this.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' AND studentBio.faculty = '" + this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"` - the last part is the `WHERE` block in which prefix `studentBio.` was added to each key column to precise to which table the filtering should be applied (because both tables ha the same key column names)

I hope it could help you in some way.